# Can stored property in Swift have getter and setter?

Tags: setter, getter, swift2

Since Swift does not have a backing ivar like in ObjC, it seems like anytime a getter/setter is used, the property automatically becomes a computed property.

Is my assumption correct or can stored property in Swift have getter/setter as well? So far all getter/setter code I have seen and used are for computed properties, and I want to make sure this is 100% correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have willSet and didSet.

That should be enough of an answer, but stackoverflow thinks it is too short :-)

Comment: So there is not really a way to create a custom getter for a stored property, correct?

Comment: Nope, there's no way. You have to create private stored property `_name` for example and computed property `name`, which does use `_name` as a backing store.

Comment: @robertvojta Thanks for confirming.